# Filter out nulls and garbage values in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown:

```
Name    Email                 Phone
Mohan   mohan.k@gmail.com     AAASWS
Shubham shubham.s@yahoo.com   1234567889
Sohail  Sohail.d@outlook.com    
Suresh  Suresh.r@gmail.com    9821345123
Kashi   kashi.y@gmail.com     Kshgatr
```

Now the phone column should contain phone numbers of individuals.

But here it is observed that it contains some missing values and also some garbage string values

I want to filter these values and label them as **"Rectify"** in the resultant Dataframe

Hence df should be as given

```
Name    Email                 Phone
Mohan   mohan.k@gmail.com     Rectify
Shubham shubham.s@yahoo.com   1234567889
Sohail  Sohail.d@outlook.com  Rectify
Suresh  Suresh.r@gmail.com    9821345123
Kashi   kashi.y@gmail.com     Rectify
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_numeric` and fill `NaN` values

```
pd.to_numeric(df.Phone, errors='coerce').fillna('Rectify')
```